# Cold Crashing in the bottle?

Tags: bottle-conditioning, secondary-fermentation, cold-crash

1. Is it possible or advantageous to cold crash after bottling?  I am aftaid if I cold crash for 2-3 weeks before I bottle that all the yeast will settle out and I wont have any to provide carbonation in the bottle.
2. If I cold crash in the bottle, will the increased sediment contribute to long-term storage issues?

Assume that I hit my FG and that no additional fermentation will take place (other than bottle carbing)

Comment: please try to keep to one question per posted question, otherwise the answers cannot be focused. Can you edit out the 3rd question (cold crash in fermentor) and move that to a separate question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to dry-hop at normal/fermentation temps for the best hop oil extraction.  Dry-hopping cold is going to be an inefficient use of precious hops.

If you're worried about (or better: experience via experiment) low bottle carbonation/refermentation, you can always pitch new yeast during bottling.  Some highly-flocculant strains might be sufficiently reduced during cold crashing to limit bottle carbonation, but I don't say that with high confidence.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I think what I will do is cold crash in the fermentor.  It looks like there will be enough yeast remaining to carbonate .

Answer (score 1):

1. You should have enough yeast still in solution after cold crashing before you bottle.  You should not have any issues with this much time.  If you were to wait a few months then I would worry.
2. If you do cold crash in the bottle there will be some increased sediment but if you are careful when you pour no a problem
3. If you are going to dry hop in your fermenter for a long time I would transfer to a secondary fermenter to get the beer of of the yeast.  If it is only for a few days I don't think there will be much issue at all.

Comment: excellent info.  I will keep that in mind.  Thanks for commenting